# How to create a BPL file in C++ Builder 4.0?

Tags: c++, c++builder

please, could you help me? How to create a BPL file in C++ Builder 4.0? I try to create but i get only lib file and not the BPL?

Comment: Are you really using  C++ Builder 4.0 in 2019?

Comment: Yes Even today i am.

Comment: Why you ask? Is it so old?

Comment: Yeah, ~25 years is quite a vintage for a programming tool.

Comment: Vintage with horror equipment will make the biggest progress. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recap (mostly for myself):

```
bpi - A Borland package import library. A .bpi is created for each package.  
bpk - The project options source file.  
bpl - The runtime package. This file is a Windows .dll with special -specific features.
      The base name for the .bpl is the base name of the .bpk.
```

Here's one example of how to create a package with one custom component:

1. File\New\Package
   [image: Package menu]
2. Add
3. New Component
   [image: New Component]
4. Select Ancestor and your class name and desired Palette Page
5. Save all - "Package1.bpk"
6. Right click on Contains and select Build
   [image]
7. Then click Install
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

If I can remember correctly, I have no Borland C++Builder4 in front of me now, but

you need to create project new Borland Package, .bpk extension. And after you decide, what should be produced as a result of build process, you will get .bpl file, Borland Package Library. If you want dual package runtime and designtime you need to check apropriate IDE options, anyway you will need .bpi in linking time if you dont need only design time package.

Comment: And how i add .bpi to project?

Comment: bpi should be automatically generated and used by IDE, unless you uncheck generate import library option.